# How can I make seaborn distribution subplots in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a 5D array called `data`

```
for i in range(10):
     sns.distplot(data[i,0,0,0], hist=False)
```

But I want to make them inside subplots instead. How can I do it?

Tried this:

```
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(4, 4))  
fig=plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3)

for i in range(10):
    ax[i].sns.distplot(data[i,0,0,0], hist=False)
plt.show()
```

This obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You would want to use the `ax` argument of the seaborn `distplot` function to supply an existing axes to it. Looping can be simplified by looping over the flattened array of axes.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3)

for i, ax in zip(range(10), axes.flat):
    sns.distplot(data[i,0,0,0], hist=False, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This way, how can one manage to further modify the subplot like adding the title or axis label, specify sticks etc., etc.

Answer (score 4):

Specify which subplot each `distplot` should fall on:

```
f = plt.figure()
for i in range(10):
    f.add_subplot(4, 3, i+1)
    sns.distplot(data[i,0,0,0], hist=False)
plt.show()
```